# Accessing Arrays in Perl hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array in a perl hash declared like this:

```
my %updatevars = (datapoints => []);
```

I'm later trying to add elements to it like this:

```
push($updatevars{'datapoints'}, [$updatestart+$i, $bandwidth]);
```

I get this error:

> Type of arg 1 to push must be array (not hash element) at dirlist.pl line 61, near "])"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hashes (and arrays) can only contain scalars. That's why we must put reference to arrays (and hashes) in them. `$updatevars{datapoints}` contains a reference to an array. As such, you need to use

```
push @{ $updatevars{datapoints} }, [ $updatestart+$i, $bandwidth ];
```

Note that your code would work on 5.14+ as `push` was changed to also accept a reference. (This change is "considered highly experimental" however, so you should use the above code in newer versions too.)

Answer (score 3):

`$updatevars{'datapoints'}` is an array ref, as you assigned it: `[]`. `push` takes an array as argument, not an array reference. So you need to dereference your reference:

```
push @{ $updatevars{'datapoints'} }, ...
```

In Perl v5.14, you may use a reference, as noted in the documentation. But it does not sound like it is a recommended practice just yet.

> Starting with Perl 5.14, "push" can take a scalar EXPR, which must
>   hold a reference to an unblessed array. The argument will be
>   dereferenced automatically. This aspect of "push" is considered highly
>   experimental. The exact behaviour may change in a future version of
>   Perl.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
push @{$updatevars{'datapoints'}}, [$updatestart+$i, $bandwidth];
```

Since `push` takes an array and `$updatevars{'datapoints'}` is an array reference, you have to de-reference it by putting the `@{}` in front.